# Eigenvalue-eigenvector equation for an operator

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, proof-verification, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

> **Proof:** *Given an eigenvalue-eigenvector equation, suppose that the state vector depends on an external parameter, e.g. time, and that
>   over it acts an operator that is the fourth derivative w.r.t. time. If
>   this operator is hermitian, find the most general operator possible
>   that satisfies these conditions and what are the boundary conditions
>   on the eigenfunctions that are needed.*

**Attempt:**

Using $\hat{A}$ as our hermitian operator and $|\psi (t) \rangle$ for its time dependent eigenvector, and $\lambda$ for its eigenvalue, I suppose the simplest eigenvalue-eigenvector equation one can write would be

$$\hat{A}|\psi (t) \rangle = \lambda |\psi (t) \rangle$$

As for the operator, I'd say it follows directly that

$$\hat{A} \sim \frac{\partial^4}{\partial t^4}, \ \ \ \lambda = \lambda^*$$

Now, based on the assumption I've been correct so far, the eigenfunctions are given by

$$\frac{d^4}{dt^4} \psi(t) = \lambda \psi(t)$$

And $\psi(t) = e^{\alpha t}$ as a possible solution immediately comes to mind, so

$$\frac{d^4}{dt^4}\left( e^{\alpha t} \right) - \lambda \left( e^{\alpha t} \right) = 0 \ \Rightarrow \alpha_{1,2} = \pm \sqrt[4]{\lambda}$$

And the general solution for the eigenfunctions is

$$\psi (t) = c_1 e^{\sqrt[4]{\lambda} t} + c_2 e^{-\sqrt[4]{\lambda}t}$$

Once again assuming I've been correct thus far, I can't find out from the provided information which boundary conditions would be required for this.

Comment: I've been thinking, since the operator is hermitian and its eigenfunctions must orthogonal, the boundary conditions are given by an analysis of $\int dt \ \psi_1^*(t) \psi_2(t) =0$?